# negative value of prediction from a training set that only contains positives

Tags: catboost

a catboost model recently gave me a % of predictions that are negative while none of the training set contains negative values for the label.

How is this possible especially in cases where the % of negative values is higher than 10% of the total predictions?

The features remain, statistically, within the training set bounds.

Comment: and i am bounded by catboost at the moment, can't use any other algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example in R, using a simple linear regression:

```
> set.seed(1)
> training_pred <- data.frame(rbind(c(1,0),c(1,0),c(0,0),c(0,0),c(0,1),c(0,1)))
> colnames(training_pred) <- paste0("V",1:2)
> training_obs <- as.vector(cbind(1,as.matrix(training_pred))%*%c(1,-.7,-.8)+
+ rnorm(nrow(training_pred),0,0.2))
> training_obs
[1] 0.17470924 0.33672866 0.83287428 1.31905616 0.26590155 0.03590632
```

All the training data are positive. Let's fit a model and predict:

```
> model <- lm(training_obs~V1+V2,training_pred)
> new_pred <- data.frame(matrix(c(1,1),nrow=1,dimnames=list(NULL,paste0("V",1:2))))
> predict(model,newdata=new_pred)
         1 
-0.6693423
```

We get a negative prediction. Note that the new predictors are squarely within the bounds of the training predictors:

```
> summary(training_pred)
       V1               V2        
 Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :0.0000  
 1st Qu.:0.0000   1st Qu.:0.0000  
 Median :0.0000   Median :0.0000  
 Mean   :0.3333   Mean   :0.3333  
 3rd Qu.:0.7500   3rd Qu.:0.7500  
 Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :1.0000  
> summary(new_pred)
       V1          V2   
 Min.   :1   Min.   :1  
 1st Qu.:1   1st Qu.:1  
 Median :1   Median :1  
 Mean   :1   Mean   :1  
 3rd Qu.:1   3rd Qu.:1  
 Max.   :1   Max.   :1
```

Here is what is going on:

[image: predictors]

In the training sample, the predictors were all at $(1,0)$, $(0,0)$ and $(0,1)$, but in prediction, they are at $(1,1)$. And each separate predictor has a negative parameter estimate:

```
> model

Call:
lm(formula = training_obs ~ V1 + V2, data = training_pred)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           V1           V2  
     1.0760      -0.8202      -0.9251
```

So you will need to look more deeply into the full *joint* distribution of your features. That they are within the training bounds is a *marginal* analysis, which is not sufficient.

Comment: thank you for your prompt reply, i will do the joint analysis now.

Regarding catboost it seems that an aggressive learning rate can be the cause as well. Investigating that possibility now.